# Get values of a Generic List<?> object in Java

Tags: java, class, generics

I am trying to created a commonMethod which acccepts a Generic List allData type and prints out the values of the alldata object received. Additionally, I am sending the className as a parameter so that we can retrieve the Class and the Fields through Reflection.

I am almost there except the part where I want to declare the className in a forloop. I know the rest of the code works, because i tried hardcoding  a ClassName and it works.

```
public void commonMethod(List<?> alldata, String className) {
      Class c = Class.forName(className);
      Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

     //I would like to define incoming className here..but failing   
      for (className c : alldata) {
          for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = null;
                value = field.get(c);
                System.out.println(value);
                //use the value in some other code
           }  
      }

 }
```

> How do I change this part 
>   **for (className c : alldata)**  to get it working..

Thanks

Comment: `for (Object c: allData)`.

Comment: You could type the method: `public <T> void commonMethod(List<T> alldata, Class<T> c) {
      /* removed: Class c = Class.forName(className); */` then use T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it the way that you want, because declaring variables to be a certain type like that (`typeName variableName`) is reserved for type names that you know at compile-time.

The proper way is to use:

```java
for (Object c : alldata) {
```

`field.get(c)` will work just fine with this, since [the `get` method takes an `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-), so `c` will have a good enough type.

Answer (score 1):

Change the generic type of the parameter List to be concrete instead of `?`, e.g. `List<T> alldata`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify your code as below to accommodate for the generics

```
public <T>void commonMethod(List<T> alldata) {
      for (T c : alldata) {
          .... 
          .....
      }

 }
```

Now Whatever class you supply, The compiler would easily understand what class it require to cast variable `c` into.

Still better is what is suggested by RC in the comments :

```
public <T> void commonMethod(List<T> alldata, Class<T> c) {
      Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

      for (T c : alldata) {
          for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = null;
                value = field.get(c);
                System.out.println(value);
                //use the value in some other code
           }  
      }

 }
```

Comment: The first part of the answer is unnecessary: just change the loop variable type to `Object`; you get nothing from the type variable other than a shorter type. On the other hand, the second part is good. The only thing I'd change would be to make it `Class<? super T>` (or `List<? extends T>`), to make it a tiny bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public <T> void commonMethod(List<T> alldata) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Sure; but this gives no advantage over `?` and `Object`.